# Advanced: Link aggregation, MPIO, iSCSI MC/S

Tags: networking, load-balancing, aggregation, networkstream

I am trying to find the proper way of accomplishing the following.

I would like to provide 2Gb/s access for clients accessing a fileserver guest vm on a ESXi server, which itself access the datastore over iSCSI. Therefore the ESXi server need 2Gbps connection to the NAS. I would also like to provide 2Gbps directly on the NAS.

Looks like there are three technology which can help. Link aggregation (802.3ad, LAG, Trunk), Multi Path IO (MPIO), and iSCSI Multiple connection per session (MC/S).

However each have their own purpose and drawbacks, Aggregation provide 2Gbps total but a single connection (I think it's based on source/dest MAC address) can only get 1Gbps, which is useless (I think for iSCSI for example which is a single stream), MPIO seem a good option for iSCSI as it balance any traffic on two connection however it seem to require 2 IPs on the Source and 2 IPs on the DEST, I am unsure about MCs.

Here is what I would like to archive, however I am not sure of the technology to employ on each NIC pair of 1Gbps.

I also think this design is flawed because doing link aggregation between the NAS and the switch would prevent me from using MPIO on the ESX as it also require 2 IP on the nas and I think link aggregation will give me a single IP.

Maybe using MCs instead of MPIO would work?

Here a diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve 2Gbps to a VM in ESX it is possible using MPIO & iSCSI but as you say you will need two adapters on the ESX host and two on the NAS. The drawback is that your NAS will need to support multiple connections from the same initiator, not all of them do. The path policy will need to be set to round-robin so you can use Active-Active connections. In order to get ESX to use both paths @ over 50% each you will need to adjust the round robin balancing mode to switch paths every 1 IOPS instead of 1000. You can do this by SSHing to the host and using esxcli (if you need full instructions on how to do that I can provide them).

After this you should be able to run IOMeter on a VM and see the data rate @ over 1Gbps, maybe 150MB/s for 1500 MTU and if you are using jumbo frames, then you will get around 200MB/s.

On another note (which might prove useful to your setups in the future), it is possible to achieve 2Gbps with two adapters on the source and bonded adapter on the NAS (so 2 → 1) when using the MPIO iSCSI Initiator that comes with Server 2008. This initiator works slightly different to VMWare and doesn't require your NAS to support many connections from one initiator — from what I can tell it spawns multiple initiators instead of sessions.